# How to find related records in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this class:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :payments

  def payable?
    amount_payable != 0
  end

end
```

How can I get the `total` of all `payments` whose `invoice` is `payable`?

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to  :invoice

  def self.total
    where("invoices.payable? = ?", true).map(&:amount).sum
  end

end
```

The problem seems to be that the `where` clause accepts only database column names and not functions like `payable?`.

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot run your Ruby methods in SQL. As the logic is simple in this one, you can do

```
where("amount_payable != ?", 0)
```

If your Ruby method cannot be expressed in pure SQL, the only way would be to fetch all records, then filter them in Ruby (which would be inefficient), like this:

```
all.select(&:payable?)
```